# how to trim x axis text to be visible in plots for python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to python. I am plotting the Bit error rate data w.r.t time and i want to remove these zeros. My x-axis values are like this hh:mm:ss:ffffff. I want to remove the seconds and microseconds as, it is occupying a lot of place on the graph/plot and they are overlapping on each other.
How can i remove the seconds and microseconds (ss::ffffff) from x ticks? and plot only hours and minutes and remove the seconds and microseconds. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `MinuteLocator` tick locator and a custom formatter (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30459539/588071))

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
```

Comment: thank you very much.. it worked.. all i need is ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))