# how to plot two very large lists in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've two lists:

```
time_str = ['06:03' '06:03' '06:04' ..., '19:58' '19:59' '19:59']
value = ['3.25' '3.09' '2.63' ..., '2.47' '2.57' '2.40']
```

I tried below code but got error:

```
    plt.plot(time_str,value)
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.show()
```

> ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 06:00

How can I plot time_str on x_axis and value on y axis. time_str has values for every minute and maybe we can show for every 15 minutes ticks on x axis.I tried in several ways but I couldn't get the line plot properly. Can anyone suggest

Edit:
After some trials, I have this code yet I don't have appropriate labels on the axis (It appears as though python just tried to scratch something):

```
   fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)  
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.MinuteLocator(interval=15))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M')) 
    plt.plot(y)
    plt.xticks(range(len(x)), x)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: plt.plot(list(range(len(time_str))), value)
    
    plt.xticks(range(len(time_str)), time_str, rotation=90)
    plt.xticks(range(1680),time_str, 15.0)
    #ax.set_xticklabels(time_str)

Answer (score 1):

You can plot every ith value using numpy's array slicing and indexing (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing)

```
#only plot every 15th value
plt.plot(time_str[::15], value[::15])
```

**In response to question update**
The value error is not associated with the size of the list. You need to cast your string as a datetime object. Something like:

```
from datetime import datetime
times = [datetime.strptime(time, '%I:%M') for time in  time_str]
```

**In response to comment**
You will have to adjust this to your needs, but using masks would be the simpliest way to get every 15 mins

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

time_str = ['06:03', '06:18', '06:28', '19:33', '19:03', '19:59']
value = np.array(['3.25', '3.09', '2.63', '2.47', '2.57', '2.40'])

times = np.array([datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M') for time in  time_str])
time_deltas = np.array([(time - times[0]).total_seconds()/60. for time in times])

plt_times = times[time_deltas%15==0]
plt_values = value[time_deltas%15==0]

plt.plot_date(plt_times, plt_values)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think plot need float values for x axis. I have tried converting to datetime and used plot_date.

Just to correct my question instead of every 15th value how can I take every 15 min's

Comment: Also I got this error when I tried to convert to datetime:
TypeError: must be string, not module

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just a correction, I want to plot all the values but the ticks on the x axis I want to display only every 15 minutes. I guess your code keeps only data which is every 15 minutes

Comment: Got it. I used code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538520/change-tick-frequency-on-x-time-not-number-frequency-in-matplotlib