# How to control a plot's tick frequency on X-axis (pandas, seaborn)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I want to plot a Pandas dataframe's values on y-axis and dates on x-axis, and control the xticks and their frequency.

datevalue is the dataframe and it looks like this:

```
datevalue.head()

    Date        Month   Value
0   2016-01-01  January 2094.70
1   2016-01-02  January 2041.90
2   2016-01-03  January 2133.34
3   2016-01-04  January 2023.25
4   2016-01-05  January 2023.98
```

To plot the values on the respective dates, I guess scatterplot would be good for this purpose. I initiate the figure and plot the scatterplot:

```
scatter_datevalue = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
scatter_datevalue = sns.set(style="whitegrid", font_scale=.6)
scatter_datevalue = sns.scatterplot(x="Date", y="value", data=datevalue)
scatter_datevalue.set(xlim=("2016-01-01", "2016-12-31"))
```

This gives me the following figure:

[image]

However, the xtick labels (is this the correct thing to call them?) show only the twelve months. Instead, I want to show the dates, and be able to **try different frequencies** (steps?) **for the ticks, for example show a tick for every day, or every 7 days or so**.

How can I do this? I've tried everything I've found but couldn't get it right.

Bonus question: as there is the "Month" column in the same dataframe, I'd like to show the month names below the date ticks (when a new month starts) if that is possible.

Comment: Did you read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538520/change-tick-frequency-on-x-time-not-number-frequency-in-matplotlib)?

Comment: I did, thanks, the links in one of the answers helped me get somewhat what I wanted...