# What could I do to change the time intervals on the x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-datareader

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web

#This makes a chart w/3 hour intervals and I would need something like 30 minutes
style.use("ggplot")
start = dt.datetime(2019,4,24)
end = dt.datetime(2019,5,25)
df = web.get_data_yahoo("TSLA", start, end)
df["Adj Close"].plot()
plt.title('Tesla Price v. First Quarter Earnings 2019')
plt.ylabel('USD')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you have some example data?

Comment: I'm actually just pulling it straight from yahoo, I couldn't give you an example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change tick frequency on X (time, not number) frequency in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538520/change-tick-frequency-on-x-time-not-number-frequency-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows how to set the primary scale at 7-day intervals and hide the secondary scale as an example. Other variations can be found on
[formatter page](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html) and [Locator page](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html).

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#This makes a chart w/3 hour intervals and I would need something like 30 minutes
style.use("ggplot")
start = dt.datetime(2019,4,24)
end = dt.datetime(2019,5,25)
df = web.get_data_yahoo("TSLA", start, end)

ax = df["Adj Close"].plot()
days = mdates.DayLocator(interval=7)
days_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(days_fmt)
ax.minorticks_off()

plt.title('Tesla Price v. First Quarter Earnings 2019')
plt.ylabel('USD')
plt.show()
```

[image]