# Convert to datetime, but how to drop '1900-01-01' in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, datetime-format

I have a time series only contains hours, minutes, and seconds, when I use datetime convert it into datetime type, it added '1900-01-01' as a date automatically. How to drop the date? I would like to get a datetime type data for further matplotlib plotting.

My code is

```
df['Time(H:M:S)']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time(H:M:S)'], format='%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: A datetime has always a date part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jens said a datetime will always have a date part.

But if you would like to remove the date, you could add `.astype(str)` to ensure that objects are in string format and apply `.apply(lambda)`, like this:

```
df['Time(H:M:S)'] = df['Time(H:M:S)'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[-1])
```

Comment: this doesn't work on a datetime series, and doesn't satisfy the OP's desire of converting the `Time(H:M:S)` *string* to a useful numeric value

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to use matplotlib to plot time series figures, here are some options:

(1) extract only the time component using `df[col].dt.time`, resulting column is string object

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time(H:M:S)': ['11:02:03', '11:22:33', '12:00:01']})
df['Time(H:M:S)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time(H:M:S)'].astype(str)).dt.time
print(df)

  Time(H:M:S)
0    11:02:03
1    11:22:33
2    12:00:01
```

(2) add today's date as prefix and convert to datetime object

```
df['Time(H:M:S)2'] = pd.to_datetime('2022-08-22 ' + df['Time(H:M:S)'].astype(str))
print(df)

  Time(H:M:S)        Time(H:M:S)2
0    11:02:03 2022-08-22 11:02:03
1    11:22:33 2022-08-22 11:22:33
2    12:00:01 2022-08-22 12:00:01
```

(3) convert to timedelta object, resulting column is timedelta object with prefix "0 days"

```
df['Time(H:M:S)3'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time(H:M:S)'].astype(str))
print(df)

  Time(H:M:S)        Time(H:M:S)2    Time(H:M:S)3
0    11:02:03 2022-08-22 11:02:03 0 days 11:02:03
1    11:22:33 2022-08-22 11:22:33 0 days 11:22:33
2    12:00:01 2022-08-22 12:00:01 0 days 12:00:01
```

(4) convert datetime into [Epoch timestamp](https://www.epochconverter.com/), resulting column is int object

```
df['Time(H:M:S)4'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time(H:M:S)'].astype(str)).astype('int64') // int(1e9)
print(df)

  Time(H:M:S) Time(H:M:S)1        Time(H:M:S)2    Time(H:M:S)3  Time(H:M:S)4
0    11:02:03     11:02:03 2022-08-22 11:02:03 0 days 11:02:03    1661166123
1    11:22:33     11:22:33 2022-08-22 11:22:33 0 days 11:22:33    1661167353
2    12:00:01     12:00:01 2022-08-22 12:00:01 0 days 12:00:01    1661169601
```

The column types are

```
print(df.info())
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype          
---  ------        --------------  -----          
 0   Time(H:M:S)   3 non-null      object         
 1   Time(H:M:S)2  3 non-null      datetime64[ns] 
 2   Time(H:M:S)3  3 non-null      timedelta64[ns]
 3   Time(H:M:S)4  3 non-null      int64
```

Comment: if you're looking for time-of-day (and not time durations) this is definitely the right answer. note the result is a vector of python [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#module-time) objects

Comment: But if I do this, the result would be a 'object', if I convert it to datetime, the year occurs again.

Comment: please let us know your downstream process, ie, what would you like to do next? If you need to do time difference, I've added some examples in my answer, check if that's what you need

Comment: I would like to use matplot to plot time series figures and the xtick should be a datetime type

Comment: I guess my second suggestion could work for you?

Comment: When I use it to plot figures, the Xticks would be like '22 11:02', while I only want it show '11:02:03', May I know how to do that?

Comment: I googled for [matplotlib set_xticks time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538520) and got this `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))`

Comment: It works, I'm starting off on the wrong foot, because what I really need to do is change the format of the X-axis, not the original data set

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a datetime, which references a specific moment in time (and must have a date attached), you can use a timedelta, which measures time increments.

```py
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({
   ...:     'Time(H:M:S)': [
   ...:         '0:01:00',
   ...:         '0:01:01',
   ...:         '1:00:00',
   ...:         '5:24:04',
   ...:         '26:14:23',
   ...:     ],
   ...: })

In [3]: df['Time(H:M:S)'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time(H:M:S)'])

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
      Time(H:M:S)
0 0 days 00:01:00
1 0 days 00:01:01
2 0 days 01:00:00
3 0 days 05:24:04
4 1 days 02:14:23
```

See the [pandas docs on timedeltas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timedeltas.html) for more info.