# Set specific tick lablels while deleting preexisting labels on an axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to set a specific tick label on a certain tick position, while deleting preexisting labels.
[image: Graph]

Specifically, The labels on the x axis are dates for the value of a stock, and I want to delete those and set one for each month instead.

Date    Open    High    Low Close/Price Volume
6/24/2019   86.78   87.11   86.06   86.55   1507828
6/25/2019   86.63   87.23   84.81   85.06   2481284
6/26/2019   85.38   85.81   84.75   85.33   2034693
6/27/2019   85.65   86.86   85.13   86.43   1394847
6/28/2019   86.66   87.74   86.66   87.55   3025379
7/1/2019    88.84   89.72   87.77   88.45   4017249
7/2/2019    89.21   90  87.95   88.87   2237183
7/3/2019    89.14   91.08   89.14   90.67   1647124

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():


    df = pd.read_excel('DatosUnited.xlsx')


    date = df['Date']
    closePrice = df['Close/Price']

    
    plt.xlabel('Tiempo')
    plt.ylabel('Valor de las acciones (USD) ')
    plt.title('Este mes')
    plt.plot(date,closePrice,'r')

    plt.show()




main()
```

I tried to delete all the tick labels, and set a list of new ones, but failed to set them in the desired position

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '6/24/2019', 1: '6/25/2019', 2: '6/26/2019', 3: '6/27/2019', 4: '6/28/2019', 5: '7/1/2019', 6: '7/2/2019', 7: '7/3/2019'}, 'Open': {0: 86.78, 1: 86.63, 2: 85.38, 3: 85.65, 4: 86.66, 5: 88.84, 6: 89.21, 7: 89.14}, 'High': {0: 87.11, 1: 87.23, 2: 85.81, 3: 86.86, 4: 87.74, 5: 89.72, 6: 90.0, 7: 91.08}, 'Low': {0: 86.06, 1: 84.81, 2: 84.75, 3: 85.13, 4: 86.66, 5: 87.77, 6: 87.95, 7: 89.14}, 'Close/Price': {0: 86.55, 1: 85.06, 2: 85.33, 3: 86.43, 4: 87.55, 5: 88.45, 6: 88.87, 7: 90.67}, 'Volume': {0: 1507828, 1: 2481284, 2: 2034693, 3: 1394847, 4: 3025379, 5: 4017249, 6: 2237183, 7: 1647124}})

date = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y') for d in df['Date']]
closePrice = df['Close/Price']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xlabel('Tiempo')
plt.ylabel('Valor de las acciones (USD) ')
plt.title('Este mes')
plt.plot(date,closePrice,'r')

locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show()
```

gives the following for your example data:

[image: example line plot]

You can replace `AutoDateLocator()` with `MonthLocator()` to just get months for certain, but this didn't look great for the example data.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538520/change-tick-frequency-on-x-time-not-number-frequency-in-matplotlib) for more info on matplotlib date locators.